# How to fill a column in excel depending on the values of previous column?

Tags: excel

Suppose i have two columns name and no.
Name.      No.
Abc.          5
Xyz.          7
Abc.         5
Abc
Abc
Xyz
Xyz

I want to fill value 5 against all Abc and 7 against all Xyz.How can i do this.. for 2 or more than 2 names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B4
=if(A4="Abc";5;if(A4="Xyz";7;"")